# What does 'example' option in a sails attribute mean?

Tags: sails.js

In [SailsJS](https://sailsjs.com/) you can define a model and provide attributes for it. This framework also provides you with a Web App code generator, which includes a model: User.js.

Many of the generated attributes for this user have an option called example, like:

```
email: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  isEmail: true,
  maxLength: 200,
  example: 'mary.sue@example.com'
},
```

But [Sails documentation about attributes](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) does not mention this 'example' option. Does it have another use besides of just hinting the developer about the attribute's use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other use, just a hint of what this field is intended for.